# cart price rule exact expiration date

Tags: magento2, cron, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes, date

Is there a way to get the exact cart price rule expiration date (the hour and minutes), I see that magento only stores the years, month, and day for **to_date** field.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box it is not possible. The table `salesrule` that holds the cart prices rules has the `to_date` field as a `date` field. This means no hours minutes and seconds. Just day, month and year.
Same goes for the `from_date` field.
If you cant you can try to change the types of these fields to `datetime`, you may also need to change the admin ui to use the calendar with time selection.
But honestly, I have no idea of the real implications of changing this. You can give it a try tough.

Comment: First thanks for your answer.     

But how does magento then know if a cart price rule gets expired if the date (year, month, and day) is the same for both form_date, to_date, but the hour or minute is different?

Comment: Sorry I mean to_date and the current date are the same in year, month, and day but different in hours or minutes

Comment: It all depends on the timezone you have set